# How to configure SQL Server named instance in IBM Websphere application server

Tags: sql-server, websphere, named-instance

Can anyone help me in configuring SQL Server named instance in IBM Websphere Application server?

With Regards
Gopinathan K. Munappy

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> Server Name: "**IPAddressServer\instanceName**"

in the **Common and required data source properties** of **Data Source Configuration**, it works for me on WAS 8.0.0.3.

Comment: Can confirm this works on WAS 7.0 also. If you're using custome properties it's called "serverName"

Answer (score 1):

Please see page 24 of Accessing Databases chapter of WAS 7 Administration and Configuration Guide for [Example: Connecting to an SQL Server database](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4577.pdf), which gives you step by step instructions.

You will have different options according to which JDBC driver you will use and kind of datasource you'll define (XA / nonXA). These options and respective configuration parameters are outlined in 
[Data source minimum required settings for Microsoft SQL Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rdat_minreqmssql.html) document at infocenter.